# Magento: Moving top.menu block next to logo

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to move top menu block right next to main logo(see picture below)

Here is screen shot what exactly I want to do.
[picture what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a42o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to edit appropriate template and adjust css if needed. In your case template you are looking for is:

*app/design/frontend/{theme}/{template}/templates/page/html/header.phtml*

where {theme} and {template} depends on what you are actually using (both are default by default).

If there is no templates/page/html directory create them and copy header.phtml from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml to your location.

Then edit this header.phtml.

By default it looks like this:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif?>
        <div class="quick-access">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
            <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

so you just move echo `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` to new location (most likely before or instead of div.quick-access).

Then adjust your css.

Comment: Yes, definitely. figuring out how to do it.

Comment: Another question: for example I have currently 4 categories like HOME | FASHION | SPORT | BEAUTY i like to do look like this HOME | PRODUCT. and in the PRODUCT category there fashion, sport and beauty categories. How can i do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: topMenu contains your categories menu (fashion,sport,beauty in your case). And it is basically a div with ul inside. Now you can add your own markup around this div.nav-container (for example another list, and of course static PRODUCT link) and with a little bit of css you can make this "sub categories" appear on PRODUCT link hover.